# Media query visual bug, unexpected behavior mobile response

Tags: css, html, mobile, media-queries

I am working on a homework assignment that should generate the following results:

**On desktop:**

[image: expected desktop]

**On mobile:**

[image: Proper mobile result]

**On tablet:**

[image: Proper tablet result]

Right now I am getting the proper desktop component but the mobile component is not loading properly at all.

**Here are some screen shots of how my result looks on tablet:**

[image: Tablet version]

**And on mobile:**

[image: Mobile 1]
[image: Mobile 2]

I don't see exactly where I am going wrong in terms of my code. Attached is the css and html I am working with.

Any clue as to what's wrong would really help me out. I am using Google chrome, Microsoft edge, and opera emulator to test.

```css
/* pacific.css for assignment #5 by Caleb Latimer*/

*{
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      color : #666666;
      font-family: Verdana;
      background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
}
h1{
      background-color: #000033;
      color : #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Georgia;
      line-height: 200%;
      background-image: url(images/sunset.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-left: 20px;
      height: 72px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-position: right;
}

h2{
      color: #3399CC;
      font-family: Georgia;
}
dt{
      color: #000033;
      font-weight: bold;
}
.resort{
      color: #000033;
      font-size: 1.2em;
}
footer{
      font-size: .70em;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#wrapper{
      width: 80%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: #90C7E3;
      min-width: 700px;
      max-width: 1024px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}
h3{
      color: #000033;
}
main{
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      display:block;
}
#homehero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/coast.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#yurthero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/yurt.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#trailhero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/trail.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
 nav ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;

}
nav a:link{
      color: #000033;
}
nav a:visited{
      color: #344873;
}
nav a:hover{
      color: #FFFFFF;
}
.left-column{
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      /*padding-top: 20px 5px 0 20px; works for some reason?*/
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;

      position: relative;
}
.left-column ul li{
      list-style: none;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
}
.right-column{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-left: 170px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 1px;
}
header,nav,main,footer{
      display: block;
}
#mobile{
  display: none;
}
#desktop{
  display: inline;
}

/* CSS media queries below */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: none;
  }
  #wrapper{
    width:auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  h1{
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav{
    float:none;
    width:auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  nav li{
    display:inline-block;
  }
  nav a{
    padding: 1em;
  }
  main{
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  footer{
    margin:0;
  }
  #homehero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #yurthero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #trailhero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only all and (max-width: 768px){
  h1{
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
  }
  nav{
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav a{
    display: block;
    padding:0.2em;
    font-size:1.3em;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #330000;
  }
  main{
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
  }
  #homehero{
    display: none;
  }
  #yurthero{
    display:none;
  }
  #trailhero{
    display:none;
  }
  footer{
    padding: 0;
  }
  #mobile{
    display: inline;
  }
  #desktop{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Chapter 5 Homework by Caleb Latimer -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
    <script src = "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif] -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css" /> <!-- Uses the pacific.css stylesheet inside of folder -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- viewport tag configuration -->
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
             <header>
                     <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
             </header>

          <nav class = "left-column">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>
            <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a> </li><!-- Doesn't lead anywhere no requirements given -->
          </ul>
          </nav>

          <div id ="homehero"></div>
          <main class = "right-column">
            <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>

            <p>
              <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.
            </p>

            <ul>
              <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
              <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
              <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
              <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
              <li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods</li>
            </ul>

            <div>
              <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br />
              12010 Pacific Trails Road <br />
              Zephyr, CA 95555<br /><br />
              <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a><br />
              <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
            </div>

          </main>

          <footer>
            Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort <br />
            <a href = "mailto:Caleb@Latimer.com">Caleb@Latimer.com</a>
          </footer>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue, the problem was with the media queries. I had css that defined `.left-column` & `.right-column` but I never overwrote it in proper context of the queries. Below is the modified CSS which solves the problem:

```
/* pacific.css for assignment #5 by Caleb Latimer*/
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      color : #666666;
      font-family: Verdana;
      background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
}
h1{
      background-color: #000033;
      color : #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Georgia;
      line-height: 200%;
      background-image: url(images/sunset.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-left: 20px;
      height: 72px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-position: right;
}
h2{
      color: #3399CC;
      font-family: Georgia;
}
dt{
      color: #000033;
      font-weight: bold;
}
.resort{
      color: #000033;
      font-size: 1.2em;
}
footer{
      font-size: .70em;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#wrapper{
      width: 80%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: #90C7E3;
      min-width: 700px;
      max-width: 1024px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}
h3{
      color: #000033;
}
main{
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      display:block;
}
#homehero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/coast.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#yurthero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/yurt.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#trailhero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/trail.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
 nav ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link{
      color: #000033;
}
nav a:visited{
      color: #344873;
}
nav a:hover{
      color: #FFFFFF;
}
.left-column{
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      position: relative;
}
.left-column ul li{
      list-style: none;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
}
.right-column{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-left: 170px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 1px;
}
header,nav,main,footer{
      display: block;
}
#mobile{
  display: none;
}
#desktop{
  display: inline;
}


/* CSS media queries below */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
  #wrapper{
    width:auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
  h1{
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
  nav{
    float:none;
    width:auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
  nav li{
    display:inline-block;
}
  nav a{
    padding: 1em;
}
  main{
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
}
  footer{
    margin:0;
  }
  #homehero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #yurthero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #trailhero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .left-column{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: inherit;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right-column{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
}

@media only all and (max-width: 768px){
  h1{
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
  }
  nav{
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav a{
    display: block;
    padding:0.2em;
    font-size:1.3em;
  }
  nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #330000;
  }
  main{
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
  }
  #homehero{
    display: none;
  }
  #yurthero{
    display:none;
  }
  #trailhero{
    display:none;
  }
  footer{
    padding: 0;
  }
  #mobile{
    display: inline;
  }
  #desktop{
    display: none;
  }
  .left-column{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: inherit;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right-column{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
}
```

and here's the snippet

```css
/* pacific.css for assignment #5 by Caleb Latimer*/
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      color : #666666;
      font-family: Verdana;
      background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
}
h1{
      background-color: #000033;
      color : #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Georgia;
      line-height: 200%;
      background-image: url(images/sunset.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-left: 20px;
      height: 72px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-position: right;
}
h2{
      color: #3399CC;
      font-family: Georgia;
}
dt{
      color: #000033;
      font-weight: bold;
}
.resort{
      color: #000033;
      font-size: 1.2em;
}
footer{
      font-size: .70em;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#wrapper{
      width: 80%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: #90C7E3;
      min-width: 700px;
      max-width: 1024px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}
h3{
      color: #000033;
}
main{
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      display:block;
}
#homehero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/coast.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#yurthero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/yurt.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
#trailhero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(images/trail.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin-left: 170px;
}
 nav ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link{
      color: #000033;
}
nav a:visited{
      color: #344873;
}
nav a:hover{
      color: #FFFFFF;
}
.left-column{
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      position: relative;
}
.left-column ul li{
      list-style: none;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
}
.right-column{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-left: 170px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 1px;
}
header,nav,main,footer{
      display: block;
}
#mobile{
  display: none;
}
#desktop{
  display: inline;
}


/* CSS media queries below */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
  #wrapper{
    width:auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
  h1{
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
  nav{
    float:none;
    width:auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
  nav li{
    display:inline-block;
}
  nav a{
    padding: 1em;
}
  main{
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
}
  footer{
    margin:0;
  }
  #homehero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #yurthero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #trailhero{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .left-column{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: inherit;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right-column{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
}

@media only all and (max-width: 768px){
  h1{
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
  }
  nav{
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav a{
    display: block;
    padding:0.2em;
    font-size:1.3em;
  }
  nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #330000;
  }
  main{
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
  }
  #homehero{
    display: none;
  }
  #yurthero{
    display:none;
  }
  #trailhero{
    display:none;
  }
  footer{
    padding: 0;
  }
  #mobile{
    display: inline;
  }
  #desktop{
    display: none;
  }
  .left-column{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: inherit;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right-column{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Chapter 5 Homework by Caleb Latimer -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
    <script src = "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif] -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css" /> <!-- Uses the pacific.css stylesheet inside of folder -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- viewport tag configuration -->
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
             <header>
                     <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
             </header>

          <nav class = "left-column">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>
            <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a> </li><!-- Doesn't lead anywhere no requirements given -->
          </ul>
          </nav>

          <div id ="homehero"></div>
          <main class = "right-column">
            <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>

            <p>
              <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.
            </p>

            <ul>
              <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
              <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
              <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
              <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
              <li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods</li>
            </ul>

            <div>
              <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br />
              12010 Pacific Trails Road <br />
              Zephyr, CA 95555<br /><br />
              <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a><br />
              <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
            </div>

          </main>

          <footer>
            Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort <br />
            <a href = "mailto:Caleb@Latimer.com">Caleb@Latimer.com</a>
          </footer>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```